# Website sessions with disabled cookies, javascript, HTTP Referer and without GET/POST?

Tags: session, cookies, https, digest

My problem is probably a very common one ;)
I want to implement user sessions for a website. The restrictions for this to work are these:

- It has to work without cookies, since they can be disabled.
- It has to work without passing the session id (or session-related id) inside the GET and/or POST form variables.
- It has to work without inspecting the HTTP Referer header field, since this might be empty.
- It has to work without JavaScript, since this can be disabled.

The only thing I found was using HTTPS (which is a good choice anyway...) and "Digest access authentication". The only shortcoming is that MD5 is used as the hashing mechanism which is considered insecure.

Is there any way of establishing a user session that cannot be hijacked easily by applying the restrictions mentioned above? And does Digest access authentication solve this and what might be the shortcomings?

Edit:
I found another approach that might work: If the site is HTTPS only then one can grab the SSL/TLS session identifier on the server side (e.g. using mod_perl if using Perl on server side) and use that session id. Note that user association with one such session id must be done separately. But still with this approach the server side always has a valid secured session id.
Is this correct?

Comment: Would remove the Javascript tag.

Comment: You could pass the session ID within the path. Easy to hijack though.

Comment: I did not explicitly rule that one out but did in my head. The session id would be part of the URL, as it would be if it was part of the GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48856/is-using-an-ssl-session-id-along-with-a-cookie-based-session-verification-more-s

The easiest and most secure approach (given the information I gathered until now) seems to be:

- The Website is HTTPS only.
- The session id *is* the SSL/TLS session identifier and this id is stored in a database and may or may not be associated with a user account record (user authentication is done using normal forms over HTTPS then).

If anyone has a better approach, I would be glad to read about it.